# Why does a multiplicative subgroup of a field have to be cyclic?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The book "A First Course in Abstract Algebra" by Fraleigh says

> If $G$ is a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group $\langle F^*,\cdot\rangle$ of a field $F$, then $G$ is cyclic. In particular, the multiplicative group of all nonzero elements of a finite field is cyclic.

I wonder why that is. Take $a,b\in F$ such that $a^2=b^2=1$. Then $\{1,a,b,ab\}$ is a non-cyclic subgroup of $F$. Where am I going wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: How are you concluding that $\{1,a,b,ab\}$ is non-cyclic?  What if $a=b$?  What if $F=\mathbb{R}$, $a = 1$, $b = -1$?  Then $\{1,a,b,ab\} = \{1,-1\}$ is certainly cyclic.

Comment: The quadratic $\,x^2-1\,$ cannot have $\,4\,$ distinct roots $\{1,a,b,ab\}$ in a field.

Comment: Your error is in presuming each element of $\{1,a,b,ab\}$ is distinct from the other three.

Comment: My initial assumption (which I realised I haven't mentioned) is that $a\neq b$.

Comment: @BillDubuque- But $x^2-1$ can have two roots- $a$ and $b$. Why do $1$ and $ab$ have to be roots too?

Comment: @Ayush Because $\,1^2 = 1,\,$ and $\,a^2 = 1 = b^2\,\Rightarrow\ (ab)^2 = a^2 b^2 = 1\cdot 1 = 1.\ \ $

Comment: Ayush, you just asked why $1$ has to be a root of $x^2-1$. Surely that's obvious...

Comment: lol in retrospect that was indeed a stupid question.

Comment: @anon:  D'oh.  (My) stupid comment deleted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\,x^2-1\,$ cannot have $\,4\,$ distinct roots $\{1,a,b,ab\}$ since a [quadratic has at most two roots](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) in a field (or domain). This property plays a key role in the proof - see below.

**Theorem** $\ $ A finite subgroup $\rm\:G\:$ of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic.

**Proof** $\ $ The proposition below yields, with  $\rm\,m = maxord(G) = expt(G),\,$ that  $\rm\, x^m = 1\,$  has  $\rm\:\#G\:$ roots.  Since a polynomial $\rm\,f\neq 0\,$ over a field [satisfies](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2049882/242) $\rm\,\#roots\ f \le deg\ f\:$  we infer that $\rm\: \#G \le m.\:$ But maxorder $\rm\:m \le \#G\:$  since  $\rm\:g^{\#G} = 1\:$ for all $\rm\:g \in G\:$ (Lagrange). $\:$ Thus $\rm\:m = \#G = maxord(G),\:$ therefore $\rm\:G\:$ has an element of order $\rm\#G,\:$ hence $\rm\:G\:$ is cyclic.

$\begin{eqnarray}\rm{\bf Proposition}\quad maxord(G) \!&\,=\,&\rm expt(G)\ \text{ for a finite abelian group}\ G,\ i.e.\\ \\
\rm max\ \{ ord(g) : \: g \in G\} \!&\,=\,&\rm  min\ \{ n>0 : \: g^n = 1\ \ \forall\ g \in G\}\end{eqnarray}$

**Proof** $\ $ By the lemma below, $\rm\: S\, =\, \{ ord(g) : \:g \in G \}$  is a finite
set of naturals closed under$\rm\ lcm$.

Hence every  $\rm\ s \in S\:$  is a
divisor of the max elt $\rm m\ $  [else  $\rm\: lcm(s,m) > m\,$],$\ $ so $\rm\ m = expt(G)$.

**Lemma** $\ $ A finite abelian group $\rm\:G\:$ has an  lcm-closed  order set, i.e. with $\rm\: o(X) = $ order of $\rm\: X$

$$\rm X,Y \in G\ \Rightarrow\ \exists\ Z \in G:\  o(Z) = lcm(o(X),o(Y))$$

**Proof** $\ \ $  By induction on  $\rm\: o(X)\, o(Y).\ $ If it's $\:1\:$ then trivially $\rm\:Z = 1$. $\ $ Otherwise

write  $\rm\ o(X) =\: AP,\: \ o(Y) = BP',\ \ P'|\,P = p^m > 1,\ $  prime $\rm\: p\:$ coprime to $\rm\: A,B.$

Then  $\rm\: o(X^P) = A,\ o(Y^{P'}) = B.\ $  By induction there's a $\rm\: Z\:$ with $\rm \: o(Z) = lcm(A,B)$

so  $\rm\ o(X^A\: Z)\: =\: P\ lcm(A,B)\: =\: lcm(AP,BP')\: =\: lcm(o(X),o(Y)).$

Comment: If you leave some details for the OP to work out on his own then you get essentially the same proof as in my answer. :)

Comment: @Amit The point of my comment was to help readers understand the relationship between the answers - nothing more. Otherwise, in threads with many related answers, a student might expend much effort before realizing that many answers are essentially duplicates. Here a reader can decide on a sketch or a complete proof, whatever works best.

Comment: Yes I know, just being snarky.

Comment: Can I ask what's the terminology of $expt(G)$?

Comment: @maplemaple $\,\rm expt(G)\,$ denotes the [exponent of the group $\rm G$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1228513/242)

Answer (score 3):

Let $G < \langle F^\ast, \cdot\rangle$ be a finite subgroup.  It suffices to show that $\mathrm{ord}(x) = |G|$ for some $x \in G$, since such an $x$ can be taken to be a generator for $G$.

Suppose not, and that the maximum order of any element of $G$ is some $n < |G|$.  It's easy to see that $x^n = 1$ for all $x \in G$, indeed, $n$ must be the least common multiple of the orders of the elements of $G$ (this fact doesn't rely on the assumption $n < |G|$).  Thus every element of $G$ is a solution to $x^n = 1$, of which there are at most $n$ in the field $F$.  So

$$\left|G\right| \leq \left|\{x\in F : x^n = 1\}\right| \leq n < \left|G\right|$$

contradiction.

Comment: If you complete the omitted parts then you get essentially the same proof as in my answer.

Comment: Finally a clear answer : )

Answer (score 1):

Sketch:  $F$ a field implies $F[x]$ a Euclidean domain implies $F[x]$ a UFD.  Since $F$ is a field, all the $F$ are the units in $F[x]$, so no degree zero polynomial is an irreducible in $F[x]$.  It is an exercise to show degree 1 irreducible polynomials have a single root in $F$.  It is an exercise to show that degree $\geq$2 irreducible polynomials have no roots in $F$.

Consider a polynomial of degree $d$ in $F[x]$.  This polynomial is the product of a unit and powers of irreducibles in $F[x]$.  The sum of the polynomial degrees of the unit (i.e. zero) and the irreducibles (counted with multiplicity) is the degree of the polynomial because $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain.  Therefore, the polynomial has $\leq d$ roots in $F$.

Let $n = |G|$ and $m = \gcd(\{|g| \, \mid \, g \in G\})$.  By Lagrange, every element's order divides $n$.  The least number divided by every element's order is $m$, so $m \leq n$.  Consider now the polynomial $P(x) = x^m-1$, which has degree $m$ and therefore has $\leq m$ roots in $F$.  Since every element of $G$ satisfies the equation $P(x)=0$, $n \leq m$.  Therefore $n = m$.

(One variant of this argument uses Euler's totient here.  I think this is usually attributed to Serre.  Can anyone confirm/deny that?)

Let $p$ range over the primes dividing $n$ such that $p^k$ exactly divides $n$ and let $\mathrm{Syl}_p$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.  If $\mathrm{Syl}_p$ is not cyclic, then every element of $\mathrm{Syl}_p$ has order $\leq p^{k-1}$.  But then the maximum power of $p$ in the factorization of $m$ is $p^{k-1}$ and that in $n$ is $p^k$.  Since $m=n$, $\mathrm{Syl}_p$ is cyclic.  For distinct primes $p$, $q$, let $g_p, g_q$ generate $\mathrm{Syl}_p$,$\mathrm{Syl}_q$, respectively.  We find that $(|g_p|,|g_q|)=1$ so $g_p g_q$ generates a cyclic group with order the product of the orders of $\mathrm{Syl}_p$ and $\mathrm{Syl}_q$.  Since $F$ is a field, $G$ is abelian so $G$ is the direct product of its Sylow subgroups.  By a quick induction, the product of a set of generators, one each from the Sylow $p$-subgroups as $p$ ranges over primes dividing $n$, generates $G$.

Comment: I vaguely recall seeing the totient version credited to someone besides Serre, but I cannot recall who at the moment.

Comment: That $\gcd$ expression was a little surprising, I think because I confused the `\mid` in the set comprehension with the bars on the order-of-$g$ notation. But I wasn't sure what I would have preferred.  Then I wondered about $$\gcd_{g\in G}(\lvert g\rvert).$$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint* A finite abelian group is cyclic iff its order equals its exponent.