# Ideal of a group

Tags: group-theory, terminology, ideals

The ideal is defined in the [ring theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_(ring_theory)#Definitions_and_motivation);

> In ring theory, a branch of abstract algebra, an ideal of a ring is a special subset of its elements

In the answer to this question [What is the exponent of a group?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1228513/338051), the term ideal is used for groups as;

> The exponent of a group $G$ is the non-negative generator of the ideal $\{z \in \mathbb{Z} : \forall g \in G (g^z=1)\}$.

Is this usage of the term *ideal* correct? If not, what is the correct term?

Comment: $\{z \in \mathbb{Z} : \forall g \in G (g^z=1)\}$ is a subset of $\mathbb Z$, and $\mathbb Z$ is certainly a ring. So, the answer is yes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The ideal $\{z \in \mathbb{Z} : \forall g \in G (g^z = 1)\}$ does not live in $G$, it lives in $\mathbb{Z}$. Because $\mathbb{Z}$ is a PID whose units are $\{1, -1\}$, we may speak of "the non-negative generator" of any ideal.

Answer (score 3):

This can be verified directly from the definition of an ideal.

Let $\mathbf I = \{z \in \mathbb{Z} : \forall g \in G (g^z=1)\} \subset \mathbb Z.$

Suppose $z_1, z_2 \in \mathbf I$. Then $\forall g \in G, g^{z_1} = g^{z_2} =1$. So $\forall g \in G, g^{(z_1+z_2)} =  g^{z_1} g^{z_2} =1$. Hence $z_1+z_2 \in \mathbf I$.

Suppose $k \in \mathbb{Z}$ and $z \in \mathbf I$. Then $\forall g \in G,g^{z} = 1$. So $g^{kz} = (g^{z})^k =1$. Hence $kz \in \mathbf I$.

It follows that $\mathbf I$ is an ideal of $\mathbf Z$.