# Is there a name the minimum $d$ such that $g^d=e$ for all $g$ in a given finite group?

Tags: group-theory, terminology, definition

Clearly, such $d$ would divide the group order, and it is divided by the order of every single element. I wonder if there is a name for such integer, and if there are certain basic properties beyond the ones I just mentioned.

Comment: It's called the exponent of the group. See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228513/what-is-the-exponent-of-a-group

Comment: In general, we say $G$ is "of exponent $n$" if $x^n=e$ for all $x\in G$. While some people use "exponent" to describe the least such $n$, this use is not universal.

Comment: Thank you, @rogerl. Right to the point. I would encourage you to submit this as an answer so that I can close the question.

Comment: Also, thanks @ArturoMagidin for the additional note.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is usually called the exponent of the group. See for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228513) or [here](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Exponent_of_a_group).

Answer (score 1):

It is known as the *exponent* of the group. The group need not be finite, either; for instance: $\prod_{n=0}^\infty \Bbb Z_2$ has exponent two.

Comment: Thanks for the added example!

Comment: You're welcome, @Daniel.