# Cyclic group Zp

Tags: abstract-algebra

How to show if $p$ is prime, then group $Z_{p}^{*}$ is cyclic.

Tip

1. Let $g$ and $h$ of a commutative group $G$ have orders $n$ and $m$ respectively. There exists and element $x \in G$ of order $LCM (n,m)$
2. In any field $\mathbb{K}$ a polynomial $f \in \mathbb{K} [x]$ of degree $n$ has at most $n$ different roots.

I have no idea.

Comment: helpful site : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/290427/is-mathbb-z-p-1-2-3-p-1-a-cyclic-group

Answer (score 7):

(In the given links I did not find a proof using exactly your hints that's why I provided this proof, but you can see other methods too)

Proving that $\Bbb Z_p^*$ is cyclic is equivalent to proving the existence of an element of order $p-1$, take $l=\text{lcm}(\text{ord}(1),\text{ord}(2),\cdots,\text{ord}(p-1))$ so it's clear that:
$$\forall k\in \Bbb Z_p^* \ \ \ \ \ \ \ k^l=1  $$
because $\text{ord}(k)|l$ for every $k$, This means that $x^l-1$ is a polynomial of degree $l$ in the field $\Bbb Z_p$ which has more than $p-1$ roots, as a consequence $l\geq p-1$.

Now because there exists an element of order $LCM(\text{ord(a)},\text{ord}(b))$ for  every two elements (This is the first hint: to prove it take just the product $ab$) there exists an element $g$ of order $l$ hence $l\leq p-1$.

Finally there exits an element $g$ of order $l=p-1$, thus $\Bbb Z_p^*$ is cyclic.

Comment: This is a special case of a proof that a finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic, e.g. [see here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/652884/242)

Comment: I'm sorry I did not see your answer

Comment: There will always be some amount of overlap or duplication on a site this large. No need to apologize for that, esp, considering that special cases often prove instructive. My comment was merely meant to inform readers about the generalization.

Answer (score 4):

We have the much more general

**Proposition.** Any finite subgroup of the multiplicative group of a field is cyclic.

*Proof.*
Let $F$ be a field and $G$ a finite subgroup of $F^\times$. Let $n=|G|$.
For $m\in\mathbb N$, let $f(m)$ denote the number of distinct $m$th roots of unity in $F$ and let $g(m)$ denote the number of distinct primitive $m$th roots (i.e., those that are not $d$th roots for any $d<m$). 
Then clearly
$$\tag1 f(m)=\sum_{d\mid m}g(d).$$
By Möbius inversion it follows that
$$\tag2 g(m)=\sum_{d\mid m}\mu(m/d)f(d).$$
Since $m$th roots of unity are roots of $P_m(X):=X^m-1$, we have $f(m)\le m$ for all $m$.
If $d\mid m$ then $$P_m(X)=P_d(X)(1+X^d+X^{2d}+\ldots+X^{m-d})$$ shows that  if $P_m$ has $m$ distinct roots, the same must hoild for $P_d$, i.e.,  if $f(m)=m$ then also $f(d)=d$.
Since $a^n=1$ for all $a\in G$, we conclude $f(n)=n$ and hence $f(d)=d$ for all $d\mid n$. 
Using $(2)$, we obtain
$$ g(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(n/d)d=\phi(n)>0.$$
Thus $G$ contains at least one element $a$ of order $n$ and hence $G=\langle a\rangle$ is cyclic. $_\square$