# The multiplicative group of nonzero elements of a finite field is cyclic (contrapositive proof)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-fields

I have seen a few proofs of this claim, but I am interested in the proof by contrapositive.
How can I show that if the multiplicative group is not cyclic then for some $n>0$, $x^n=1$ has more than n solutions in F, the finite field?
Then I can show that since $x^n=1$ has at most n solutions (or is it exactly n solutions?) in F, the multiplicative group is cyclic.

Comment: See e.g. [this method of proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/652884/242) in the linked dupe.

Answer (score 3):

$F^\times$ has $k$ elements. If it is not cyclic then (since it is abelian) the lcm $m$ of the order of its elements is smaller than $k$. So $x^m-1$ has $k>m$ roots in $F$.

Comment: @AnneBauval Obviously $F^\times$ is abelian

Comment: Oh yes, "[obviously ;-)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem)" (I forgot that the french translation of "field" is "corps *commutatif*").